# the importance of isolation in a BLDC drive

Tags: power, safety, brushless-dc-motor

i am designing a 3 phase inverter to run a BLDC motor, i am using ir2110 half-bridge drivers.
 i am wondering what are the benefits from optically isolating the control side from the power side?

the BLDC motor is (120V-4kW).
[image: this is the suggested configuration in the application-note]

Answer (score 1):

1. Compliance with safety requirements.
2. It reduces problems with conducted electrical noises which could affected uC without galvanic isolation.